# MvcMiniProfiler.dll vs MiniProfiler.dll

Tags: visual-studio, c#-4.0, mvc-mini-profiler

In a C# prject, What is the difference between MvcMiniProfiler.dll  (version 1.7) and MiniProfiler.dll (2.1) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both the same thing, MiniProfiler.dll (2.1) is the latest version. The project got renamed from MvcMiniProfiler to just MiniProfiler around the 2.0 time; because it is also usable on Ruby now (i.e. it's not just an 'mvc' profiler anymore).

See [here](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2012/02/22/miniprofiler-2-0-almost-out-of-the-gate), specifically the section *"No longer MVCMiniProfiler"*